# Mysql Count

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
select MIN(q.a), * FROM 
   (
     sub-query1
   ) as q
   UNION
   sub-query2
```

How can I return the number of elements in query1 as a row of master-query?

---

If i use count (*) i´ve only the count

CountElementSub-Query1

i need some like that

```
rowA, rowB, rowC, CountElementSub-Query1
rowA, rowB, rowC, CountElementSub-Query1
rowA, rowB, rowC, CountElementSub-Query1
rowA, rowB, rowC, CountElementSub-Query1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a groupwise min/max:

http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/groupwise-max/

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a subquery as a column definition in your select?